# Calculate the volume under a gridded surface in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, volume, numerical-integration

I have a non-uniformly spaced x,y,z data (Eastings, Nothings and thickness) which I have gridded and plotted as a surface using `meshgrid`, `griddata` and `surf`.

I would like to calculate the volume under this surface but I'm struggling to apply other answers to this question to my dataset and code in question (I am a complete Matlab beginner).

Any ideas how to do this (on Matlab version 2011b)? Thanks in advance.

```
load E.txt, load N.txt, load Z.txt;
[xi, yi] = meshgrid(25.351639:0.00025:25.426483, 36.363799:0.0005:36.458845);
zi = griddata(E,N,Z, xi,yi, 'linear');
surf(xi,yi,zi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`griddata` interpolates the data so that it's uniformly spaced on the `xi`,`yi`,`zi` grid. So you could sum up all `zi` values and multiply the result by the base area, which is `dx*dy`:

```
dx = 0.00025;
dy = 0.0005;
vol = dx*dy*sum(zi(:));
```

If some of the `zi` values are NaN, do this instead:

```
vol = dx*dy*sum(zi(~isnan(zi)));
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Unfortunately, I get a volume of 'NaN' when I attempt the above - probably because there are a lot of NaN generated by griddata. Any ideas how to exclude these values in the vol calculation?

Comment: This assumes that all NaN values represent zero. The question is not very clear but @user2663548 you should consider whether you want to do interpolation instead. (So think about the meaning of the NaN values)